# HIDRAW* numbers are changing after reboot ? how to fix it?

Tags: linux, embedded, hid, raspberry-pi4, udev

Shall, I need to write a udev rule. Every time it is changing after the system Linux reboots.

Comment: It is supposed to be that way, writing udev should surely help.

Comment: can you please help ? how should I proceed with it? Thanks